# Split string based on regex pattern

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a message which I am trying to split.

```
import re

message = "Aug 10, 17:04 UTCThis is update 1.Aug 10, 15:56 UTCThis is update 2.Aug 10, 15:55 UTCThis is update 3."

split_message = re.split(r'[a-zA-Z]{3} (0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]), ([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9] UTC', message)

print(split_message)
```

**Expected Output:**

```
["This is update 1", "This is update 2", "This is update 3"]
```

**Actual Output:**

```
['', '10', '17', "This is update 1", '10', '15',  "This is update 2", '10', '15', "This is update 3"]
```

Not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using "capturing groups", this is why their content is also part of the result array. You'll want to use non capturing groups (beginning with `?:`):

```
import re

message = "Aug 10, 17:04 UTCThis is update 1.Aug 10, 15:56 UTCThis is update 2.Aug 10, 15:55 UTCThis is update 3."

split_message = re.split(r"[a-zA-Z]{3} (?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]), (?:[0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9] UTC", message)

print(split_message)
```

You will however always get an empty entry first, because an empty string is in front of your first split pattern:

```
['', 'This is update 1.', 'This is update 2.', 'This is update 3.']
```

---

As statet in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

> If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all
> groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting
> list.

Comment: `print([x for x in split_message if x])` will remove the empty elements.

Answer (score 0):

Not using regex, but wanted to highlight the power of Python string splitting for tasks like this. Way less headaches as easier to understand.

```
message = "Aug 10, 17:04 UTCThis is update 1.Aug 10, 15:56 UTCThis is update 2.Aug 10, 15:55 UTCThis is update 3."
values = message.split("UTC")
values = values[1:]
result = [v.split(".")[0] for v in values]
```

Note: this may not work if your messages ("This is update 1.") contain multiple  . symbols.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It won't work for my use-case. As you mentioned my message may have multiple "." or none at all or it can also have 'UTC' in it. Only thing I am certain is that it will have date pattern like(Aug 10, 17:04 UTC) and that's why going after regex for solution.

Comment: Ah yes, the value of context. Looks like Aram Becker has given a good answer. Will leave this answer here in case anyone finds it valuable in the future.